# Counterexample for Mazur–Ulam theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

> We know,  **Mazur–Ulam theorem** states that if **$V$** and **$W$** are normed spaces over **$\mathbb{R}$** and the mapping
>   **$f\colon V\to W$**
>   is a ***surjective isometry***, then $f$ is **affine**.

Can somebody say counterexample when $f\colon V\to W$ is no surjective then f is not affine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ by $f(x) = (x, \left|x\right|)$. If $\mathbb R$ is endowed with the usual norm given by the absolute value, and $\mathbb R^2$ with the maximum norm $\left|x\right|_\infty = \max\{|x_1|, |x_2|\}$, then $f$ is an isometry.

Answer (score 3):

I think that $f\colon \mathbb R\to L^1(\mathbb R)$ defined by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1_{[0,x]}&\text{if}\ x\geq 0\\ -1_{[0,-x]}&\text{if}\ x<0\end{cases}$$

is also a counterexemple.

Answer (score 2):

An other example: the space of the bounded serie provided of the norm of the supremum. We can consider the map $\varphi$ who at the serie $u_0,u_1,u_2,...$ associate the serie $\sin(u_0),u_0,u_1,u_2,...$.