# Is any isometry on a Euclidean space affine?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $\mathbb R^n$ be the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space equipped with the usual norm and let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be an isometry (meaning it preserves the distance of any two points). I wonder if $f$ is automatically affine, namely $f-f(0)$ is linear.

By the Mazur-Ulam theorem, any bijective isometry between any two normed linear spaces is affine. Here I am dropping the bijectivity but add the restriction that both spaces are $\mathbb R^n$.

[These counterexamples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884539/counterexample-for-mazur-ulam-theorem) do not address my question. Note also that we do not know the image of $f$ is a linear subspace or not.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem), "For strictly convex spaces the result [Mazur-Ulam Theorem] is true, and easy, even for isometries which are not necessarily surjective." Finite-dimensionality is not necessary, but strict convexity is.

Comment: This is classical geometry.  Any isometry between subsets of $\mathbb R$ extends to an isometry of the whole of $\mathbb R^n$ onto itself.  Any isometry of the whole of $\mathbb R^n$ is made up of composing  translations, reflections, rotations .  All of these are affine.

Comment: More generally all isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with superposition are the Lie group $Iso(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and every isometry is a case of affine map, so $Iso(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a subgroup of $Aff(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of all affine transforms.